# Merge the table based on date and condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t

CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    dt datetime,
    type int,
    grp int,
    typecol1 varchar(10),
    typecol2 varchar(10),
    typecol3 varchar(10),
    typecol4 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO t (dt,type,grp,typecol1,typecol2,typecol3,typecol4) 
VALUES
('2019-01-15',1,1,'A',null,null,null),
('2019-01-15',2,2,null,'B',null,null),
('2019-01-15',3,3,null,null,'C',null),
('2019-01-15',4,4,null,null,null,'D'),
('2019-02-15',1,1,'AA',null,null,null),
('2019-02-15',4,2,null,null,null,'DD'),
('2019-03-15',3,1,null,null,'CCC',null),
('2019-04-15',2,1,null,'BBBB',null,NULL);
```

In this table *type* will be 1,2,3,4..  here date and type both  are composite key.

I need to merge the row based if same date exist to single row 
and merge based on only below condition

```
if same date & 
   type=1 then merge to typecol1
   type=2 then merge to typecol2
   type=3 then merge to typecol3
   type=4 then merge to typecol4
```

and grp col is  based on running count of date.

[image: Expected Out put :]

Comment: i have tried with lead function but no result ..but i dnt no how to do lead based on type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ffaa99addc5cb6375fa2fe447b4e88d)**

```
SELECT dt, MAX(typecol1) typecol1, MAX(typecol2) typecol2, MAX(typecol3) typecol3,
       MAX(typecol4) typecol4
FROM t
GROUP BY dt
```

**Output**

```
dt                  typecol1    typecol2    typecol3    typecol4
15/01/2019 00:00:00 A           B           C           D
15/02/2019 00:00:00 AA                                  DD
15/03/2019 00:00:00                         CCC 
15/04/2019 00:00:00             BBBB
```

Comment: thanks fr anwer ..is max col on varchar is safe if instead of null if empty string??

Comment: @Ljt Yes its safe and you are not bringing the values by comparing but you are just comparing the values with `NULL` or `EMPTY`, so it will give you perfect result.

Answer (score 1):

You just need grouping by `ID` with `MAX()` aggregation for rest of the columns :

```
SELECT dt,MAX(typecol1) as typecol1,
          MAX(typecol2) as typecol2,
          MAX(typecol3) as typecol3,
          MAX(typecol4) as typecol4
  FROM t
 GROUP BY dt
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecbafbc78e29276414ac2cb08b5ec776)</kbd>